# How to annotate a pdf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of filenames which I am importing to R.
Within a for loop I use read_tsv to make a df and then make several plots from that df.
I use ggarange to make and save a multi page pdf then move to the next loop.

Everything is working until I try to add annotation to the pdf like the **Annotate the arranged figure** example here:
[ggpubr publication ready plots](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/)

It works *with* annotation if I do a *single page* pdf.
It works if I do a *multipage* pdf *without* annotation.
It *doesn't* work with a *multipage* pdf *with* annotation (I get a blank pdf)

eg: my df are similar to this

```
 Sample_ID <- c("P1014B", "P1014F", "P1036A")
  SCORE <- c(1500,2000,2500)
  SCORE2 <- c(1254, 2100,2550)
  SCORE3 <- c(1599, 1900, 2533)
  SCORE4 <- c(1400, 1995, 2400)
  SCORE5 <- c(1376, 2300, 2600)
  df<- data.frame(Sample_ID, SCORE, SCORE2,SCORE3,SCORE4, SCORE5)

> df
      Sample_ID SCORE SCORE2 SCORE3 SCORE4 SCORE5
    1    P1014B  1500   1254   1599   1400   1376
    2    P1014F  2000   2100   1900   1995   2300
    3    P1036A  2500   2550   2533   2400   2600
```

Then I make the plots and arrange something like:

```
 fn<- c("file1","file2","file3","file4")
  
  for (i in 1:length(fn)){
 
    df<- read_tsv(fn[i])

colors<- c("Lower Limit 1500" = "red")
  a <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Sample_ID,y=`SCORE2`)) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity", fill="cyan4") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=SCORE[1]), col = colors, size = 1.5, linetype=2, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = `SCORE2`), nudge_y=4) +
    ggtitle("Median Score") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colors)
  
  colors<- c("Lower Limit 2000" = "red")
  b <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Sample_ID,y=`SCORE3`)) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity", fill="cyan4") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=SCORE[2]), col = colors, size = 1.5, linetype=2, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = `SCORE3`), nudge_y=4) +
    ggtitle("Median Score") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colors)
  
  
  colors<- c("Lower Limit 2500" = "red")
 c <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Sample_ID,y=`SCORE4`)) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity", fill="cyan4") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=SCORE[1]), col = colors, size = 1.5, linetype=2, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = `SCORE4`), nudge_y=4) +
    ggtitle("Median Score") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colors)
  
 
 colors<- c("Lower Limit 1500" = "red")
 d <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Sample_ID,y=`SCORE5`)) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity", fill="cyan4") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=SCORE[1]), col = colors, size = 1.5, linetype=2, show.legend = TRUE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = `SCORE5`), nudge_y=4) +
    ggtitle("Median Score") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=colors)
 
 
 ############ create the pdf
 
 ############# with annotation one page works
  
 pdf(file=paste0(fn[1]," with annotation one page.pdf"))
 
 figure <- ggarrange(a, b + font("x.text", size = 10),
                     ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
 annotate_figure(figure,
                 top = text_grob(paste0("QC Report\n",fn[1],"\n"), color = "red", face = "bold", size = 14),
                 bottom = text_grob( paste0("Date of run: \n  ", my_date, "  "), color = "#80919E",
                                     hjust = 1, x = 1, face = "italic", size = 10)
 )
 
 
 dev.off()
 
 }
 
  #############  without annotation two page works
  
  pdf(file=paste0(fn[1]," without annotation two page.pdf"))
  
 figure<-(ggarrange(a, b ,
                  ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                  ggarrange(c, d,  ncol=1,nrow=2) ))

  print(figure)
  dev.off()
  
  
  
  ############# with annotation two page doesn't work
  
  pdf(file=paste0(fn[1]," with annotation two page.pdf"))
  
  figure<-(ggarrange(a, b ,
                     ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
                     ggarrange(c, d,  ncol=1,nrow=2) ))
  
   annotate_figure(figure,
                   top = text_grob(paste0("QC Report\n",fn[1],"\n"), color = "red", face = "bold", size = 14),
                   bottom = text_grob( paste0("Date of run: \n  ", my_date, "  "), color = "#80919E",
                                       hjust = 1, x = 1, face = "italic", size = 10))

  dev.off()
```

I get a blank pdf with the error:

```
Error in gList(list(`1` = list(data = list(), layers = list(<environment>,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

Comment: Hello, please share the code in which you got the error and a minimally [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example. It is not possible to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: Hello user, it is very strange. Seems that the only solution is to create two figures, `figure1 <- ggarrange(a, b,  ncol=1,nrow=2)` and  `figure2 <- ggarrange(c, d,  ncol=1,nrow=2)`,  annotate it separatedly `figure1 <- annotate_figure(figure1, top= .....)` same to `figure2`, then finally  output `ggarrange(figure1, figure2,  ncol=1,nrow=1)` last step with one row and column in order to generate a page for each plot. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @RicVillalba will give it a go. I'm a newbie and have just realised that this is much easier if I do it in R Markdown......

Comment: p.s. Not sure if it matters too much but could you now give my question an up vote